# Add values from rows based on conditions from two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame that looks like this:

| time | name | count | variable4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0500 | unit1 | 4 | nan |
| 0500 | unit1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0500 | unit2 | 2 | nan |
| 0500 | unit3 | 4 | nan |
| 0500 | unit3 | 1 | 2 |
| 0600 | unit1 | 8 | nan |

What I want is this:

| time | name | count | variable4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0500 | unit1 | 5 | 1 |
| 0500 | unit2 | 2 | nan |
| 0500 | unit3 | 5 | 2 |
| 0600 | unit1 | 8 | nan |

Basically, I want to combine the rows and add the values in the count and variable4 column if the values in both time *and* name are equal. I've tried groupby with sum() as
`df.groupby(['time','name'])(['count', 'variable4']).sum()` but the error says DataFrameGroupBy object is not callable. I don't think I can pass two columns into sum like that, but I am unsure how else to do it. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the object `df.groupby(['time','name'])` you are calling by passing `['count', 'variable4']` as argument. So you can do this only on some special classes called Callable classes [refer](https://medium.com/swlh/callables-in-python-how-to-make-custom-instance-objects-callable-too-516d6eaf0c8d). Thats where you are getting error.

Replace () enclosing `['count', 'variable4']` after groupby to []

```py
df.groupby(['time','name'])[['count', 'variable4']].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses are invalid, just do:

```
df.groupby(['time','name']).sum()
```

Or:

```
df.groupby(['time','name'])[['count', 'variable4']].sum()
```